# Juniper EX3300 routing issue

Tags: juniper, junos

The routing on my Juniper EX3300 does not seem to be working. My ISP's gateway is at xx.xx.xx.xx. And I have the following in the configuration:

```
routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 {
            next-hop xx.xx.xx.xx;
            retain;
        }
    }                                   
}
```

I can ping to my ISP's gateway from the switch. However, I can NOT ping to any other IP. When I do a traceroute (to Google.com's IP). This is what I get:

```
traceroute to 74.125.224.69 (74.125.224.69), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
traceroute: sendto: No route to host
 1 traceroute: wrote 74.125.224.69 40 chars, ret=-1
 *traceroute: sendto: No route to host
```

Do I need to enable any protocols? I guess this goes without saying, but I am kind of new to Junos.

Update:
This is the output from `show interfaces terse | match inet`:

```
bme0.32768              up    up   inet     128.0.0.1/2     
jsrv.1                  up    up   inet     128.0.0.127/2   
vlan.0                  up    up   inet     10.0.1.1/24     
vlan.1                  up    up   inet     xx.xx.xx.110/30
```

and this is the output from: `show route forwarding-table`:

```
Routing table: default.inet
Internet:
Destination        Type RtRef Next hop           Type Index NhRef Netif
default            perm     0                    rjct    36     1
0.0.0.0/32         perm     0                    dscd    34     1
10.0.1.0/24        intf     0                    rslv  1321     1 vlan.0
10.0.1.0/32        dest     0 10.0.1.0           recv  1319     1 vlan.0
10.0.1.1/32        intf     0 10.0.1.1           locl  1320     2
10.0.1.1/32        dest     0 10.0.1.1           locl  1320     2
10.0.1.3/32        dest     1 0:25:90:63:26:53   ucst  1331     2 vlan.0
10.0.1.255/32      dest     0 10.0.1.255         bcst  1318     1 vlan.0
```

Comment: Can you show me the output of `show int terse | match inet` and `show route forwarding-table`?

Comment: @bahamat I updated the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can see that this is because your system doesn't have a default route installed, for some reason. Compare your forwarding table with mine:

```
> show route forwarding-table          
Routing table: default.inet
Internet:
Destination        Type RtRef Next hop           Type Index NhRef Netif
default            user     2 0:13:5f:3:af:8f    ucst   580     5 fe-0/0/0.0
default            perm     0                    rjct    36     1
0.0.0.0/32         perm     0                    dscd    34     1
```

Notice that `default` is listed twice for me. One with type `ucst` and once with `rjct` and yours only has one line with `rjct`. That reject is why you're seeing `no route to host`.

My best guess is that the routing daemon needs to be restarted. You could try deactivating the routing options and commiting, then re-activating it. I also don't think that you need the `retain` property on the `next-hop`. It's unnecessary in most normal situations.

A safe way to do this effectively if the unit is remote is to deactivate it and then issue `commit confirmed 5`. This will automatically roll back the configuration after 5 minutes.

I've also encountered times where I had to reboot the device to get the routing table to settle properly, so if it doesn't work after the above procedure then just try rebooting.

Of course, that is assuming that you didn't typo the `next-hop`. Since you didn't list it I can't say for certain, but according to your routing table and interface configuration the `next-hop` should be `[REDACTED]`. If that doesn't match what you have then there's your problem.

Comment: Deactivating the route and reactivating it worked. Its strange, cuz I tried it before.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why that happens, but I've seen it come up every once in a while.

Comment: Nobody is pointing out he's trying to route a private network to a public one on a router that doesn't support address translation?

Comment: The IP addresses were changed to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the routing policy, check if the next-hop is in ARP table.

ps. just guessing, but basically this might be the case.